# Finite tilings in one dimension

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, binary, tiling

The purpose of this challenge is to determine if a collection of one-dimensonal pieces can be tiled to form a finite continuous chunk.

A **piece** is a non-empty, finite sequence of zeros and ones that starts and ends with a one. Some possible pieces are `1`, `101`, `1111`, `1100101`.

**Tiling** means arranging the pieces so that a single contiguous block of ones is formed. A one from one piece can occupy the place of a zero, but not of a one, from another piece.

Equivalently, if we view a one as being "solid material" and a zero as a "hole", the pieces should fit so as to form a single stretch, without leaving any holes.

To form a tiling, pieces can only be **shifted** along their one-dimensional space. (They cannot be split, or reflected). Each piece is used exactly once.

## Examples

The three pieces `101`, `11`, `101` can be tiled as shown in the following, where each piece is represented with the required shift:

```
  101
11
   101
```

so the obtained tiling is

```
111111
```

As a second example, the pieces `11011` and `1001101` cannot be tiled. In particular, the shift

```
 11011
1001101
```

is not valid because there are two ones that collide; and

```
11011
  1001101
```

is not valid because the result would contain a zero.

## Additional rules

The **input** is a collection of one or more pieces. Any reasonable format is allowed; for example:

- A list of strings, where each string can contain two different, consistent characters;
- Several arrays, where each array contains the positions of ones for a piece;
- A list of (odd) integers such the binary representation of each number defines a piece.

The **output** should be a truthy value if a tiling is possible, and a falsy value otherwise. Output values need not be consistent; that is, they can be different for different inputs.

[Programs or functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) are allowed, in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073). [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

Each input is on a different line

#### Truthy

```
1
111
1, 1
11, 111, 1111
101, 11, 1
101, 11, 101
10001, 11001, 10001
100001, 1001, 1011
10010001, 1001, 1001, 101
10110101, 11001, 100001, 1
110111, 100001, 11, 101
1001101, 110111, 1, 11, 1
```

#### Falsy

```
101
101, 11
1, 1001
1011, 1011
11011, 1001101
1001, 11011, 1000001
1001, 11011, 1000001, 10101
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124187/find-subset-factors)

Comment: The infinite version of this problem might be interesting as well (i.e. whether a set of tiles can completely fill the 1D line without overlaps). Then stuff like `101101` would be truthy, even though no finite number of them result in a contiguous block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
+"FṢIP
FSṗLç€ċ1
```

Takes a list of indices and returns a positive integer (truthy) or **0** (falsy).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19bye3hzkWeAVxuwQ93Tvc5vPxR05oj3Yb///@PjjbUUTCO1VEA0UZgOjZWQRlIGQAFDEE4FgA) or [verify most test cases](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19bye3hzkWeAVxuwQ93Tvc5vPxR05oj3Yb/XUKADAg63A6h3f//j46ONozV4VJQiDY0hDF0FOBCQCaUgAkZgLkIJXC@AVzEACIGoUA8hARUCKLeMBYkER2NpBWsEeEMJL2GMD1Ql0EFDAyRLYbYC5UB2xwbCwA).

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>74</s> <s>73</s> 70 bytes

Takes input as an array of 32-bit integers. Returns a boolean.

```js
f=([n,...a],x)=>n?[...f+''].some(_=>n&&!(x&n)&f(a,x|n,n<<=1)):!(x&-~x)
```

Or **66 bytes** with inverted truthy/falsy values:

```js
f=([n,...a],x)=>n?[...Array(32)].every(_=>x&n|f(a,x|n,n*=2)):x&-~x
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=([n,...a],x)=>n?[...f+''].some(_=>n&&!(x&n)&f(a,x|n,n<<=1)):!(x&-~x)

console.log('[Truthy]')
console.log(f([0b1]))
console.log(f([0b111]))
console.log(f([0b1,0b1]))
console.log(f([0b11,0b111,0b1111]))
console.log(f([0b101,0b11,0b1]))
console.log(f([0b101,0b11,0b101]))
console.log(f([0b10001,0b11001,0b10001]))
console.log(f([0b100001,0b1001,0b1011]))
console.log(f([0b10010001,0b1001,0b1001,0b101]))
console.log(f([0b10110101,0b11001,0b100001,0b1]))
console.log(f([0b110111,0b100001,0b11,0b101]))
console.log(f([0b1001101,0b110111,0b1,0b11,0b1]))

console.log('[Falsy]')
console.log(f([0b101]))
console.log(f([0b101,0b11]))
console.log(f([0b1,0b1001]))
console.log(f([0b1011,0b1011]))
console.log(f([0b11011,0b1001101]))
console.log(f([0b1001,0b11011,0b1000001]))
console.log(f([0b1001,0b11011,0b1000001,0b10101]))
```

#### How?

```js
f = (                       // f = recursive function taking:
  [n, ...a],                //   n = next integer, a = array of remaining integers
  x                         //   x = solution bitmask, initially undefined
) =>                        //
  n ?                       // if n is defined:
    [... f + ''].some(_ =>  //   iterate 32+ times:
      n &&                  //     if n is not zero:
        !(x & n)            //       if x and n have some bits in common,
        &                   //       force invalidation of the following result
        f(                  //       do a recursive call with:
          a,                //         the remaining integers
          x | n,            //         the updated bitmask
          n <<= 1           //         and update n for the next iteration
        )                   //       end of recursive call
    )                       //   end of some()
  :                         // else (all integers have been processed):
    !(x & -~x)              //   check that x is a continuous chunk of 1's
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
V§=OŀF×+ṠṀṪ+oŀṁ▲
```

Takes a list of lists of 1-based indices.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkHtiffGjpsaiQ9v@hx1abut/tMHt8HTthzsXPNzZ8HDnKu38o0Cq8dG0Tf///4@ONoyN5QKSOkY6xhBWrA5CDMQGy0BpHROoDFQESS2SCMwkHVOoPghtChU1A/NMICrhJproWCCJm6CYA1SlYwaVh5lmhuxOoLwp1FwzLO4AyZpDdcNVYvEBqk/goYHwNYarweZB1IDtgNqHsAvMwi0OMQ0YMgA)

### Explanation

```
V§=OŀF×+ṠṀṪ+oŀṁ▲  Implicit input, say x=[[1,3],[1]]
              ṁ▲  Sum of maxima: 4
            oŀ    Lowered range: r=[0,1,2,3]
        ṠṀ        For each list in x,
          Ṫ+      create addition table with r: [[[1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[4,6]],
                                                 [[1],[2],[3],[4]]]
     F×+          Reduce by concatenating all combinations: [[1,3,1],[1,3,2],...,[4,6,4]]
V                 1-based index of first list y
    ŀ             whose list of 1-based indices [1,2,...,length(y)]
 §=               is equal to
   O              y sorted: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
FLḶ0ẋ;þ⁸ŒpS€P€1e
```

A monadic link taking a list of lists of ones and zeros returning either `1` (truthy) or `0` (falsey).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/N5@GObQYPd3VbH973qHHH0UkFwY@a1gQAsWHq////o6MNdQx0DGN1kGjD2FgA)** or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/N5@GObQYPd3VbH973qHHH0UkFwY@a1gQAsWHqf5fD7UDG///R0YYGhrE6XAogWkfBEMoGsgwQ4mAuTArGNzBE6IRohUkYwLVCdSAMhQqAVEMIFLvhCuBchA1QKwygViDEoSIwN8YCAA) (shortened - first 6 falseys followed by first eight truthys since the length four ones take too long to include due to the use of the Cartesian product).

#### How?

```
FLḶ0ẋ;þ⁸ŒpS€P€1e - Link: list of lists, tiles
F                - flatten (the list of tiles into a single list)
 L               - length (gets the total number of 1s and zeros in the tiles)
  Ḷ              - lowered range = [0,1,2,...,that-1] (how many zeros to try to prepend)
   0             - literal zero
    ẋ            - repeat = [[],[0],[0,0],...[0,0,...,0]] (the zeros to prepend)
       ⁸         - chain's left argument, tiles
      þ          - outer product with:
     ;           -   concatenation (make a list of all of the zero-prepended versions)

        Œp       - Cartesian product (all ways that could be chosen, including man
                 -   redundant ones like prepending n-1 zeros to every tile)
          S€     - sum €ach (good yielding list of only ones)
            P€   - product of €ach (good yielding 1, others yielding 0 or >1)
              1  - literal one
               e - exists in that? (1 if so 0 if not)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
FLḶ0ẋ;þµŒpSP$€1e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/N5@GObQYPd3VbH953aOvRSQXBASqPmtYYpv53Odx@dNLDnTNA3Mj//6OjDQ0MY3W4FEC0joIhlA1kGSDEwVyYFIxvYIjQCdEKkzCAa4XqQBgKFQCphhAodsMVwLkIG6BWGECtQIhDRWBujAUA)

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

I developed this completely independently of Jonathan Allan but now looking at his is exactly the same:

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 159 bytes

```python
lambda x:g([0]*sum(map(sum,x)),x)
g=lambda z,x:x and any(g([a|x[0][j-l]if-1<j-l<len(x[0])else a for j,a in enumerate(z)],x[1:])for l in range(len(z)))or all(z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUxLCoMwEN17iixnSgTTpehJ0iymGK0So/iBKL17mqAtlmF@7zduy2uwd1@XD2@of1bEXN6AzNRtXnvoaYSwuUMMnTTlqdm5yx0jW4XeIOjp7YJHdqlRbZ2KIhyF0RYiitrMmhGrh4l1nFhrmbZrrydaNOyouJMiVxhpE8mJbKMhundEDCgZE04/Tq1doAYpBRc843EKxZmMz1Hn@0OFUojJ1XhVHRn/CdnF/A3wHw)

Comment: [153 bytes](https://tio.run/##VUzRCoMwDHz3K/qYjgzsHkW/pCujw@qUWsUpVNm/dynqcIRLcpfcDcv06t0tVMU9WN09S818VoNM1eU9d9DpAWii55yQ1MX@s6JHUxg3d2bUk8k8064kLEBe/YGryNurza1x4CmLx2tcJKmKV/3IWtSscczAyhV6KbJNtvg4ZE5UW0tbGMbGTVCBlAIFphi7UMhkJFvt9KcKpThPzsbz15bxn5CezEdA@AI)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 74 bytes

```
f=:3 :'*+/1=*/"1+/"2(l{."1 b)|.~"1 0"_ 1>,{($,y)#<i.l=:+/+/b=:>,.&.":&.>y'
```

I might try to make it tacit later, but for now it's an explicit verb. I'll explain the ungolfed version. It takes a list of boxed integers and returns `1` (truthy) or `0` (falsy).

```
This will be my test case, a list of boxed integers:
   ]a=:100001; 1001; 1011                
┌──────┬────┬────┐
│100001│1001│1011│
└──────┴────┴────┘
b is the rectangular array from the input, binary digits. Shorter numbers are padded
with trailing zeroes:
   ]b =: > ,. &. ": &.> a   NB. Unbox each number, convert it to a list of digits 
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 0

l is the total number of 1s in the array: 
   ]l=: +/ +/ b             NB. add up all rows, find the sum of the resulting row)
7

r contains all possible offsets needed for rotations of each row: 
   r=: > , { ($,a) # < i.l  NB. a catalogue of all triplets (in this case, the list
has 3 items) containing the offsets from 0 to l:
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 0 3
0 0 4
 ...
6 6 3
6 6 4
6 6 5
6 6 6

m is the array after all possible rotations of the rows of b by the offsets in r. 
But I first extend each row of b to the total length l:
   m=: r |."0 1"1 _ (l {."1 b)  NB. rotate the extended rows of b with offsets in r,
ranks adjusted

For example 14-th row of the offsets array applied to b:
    13{r
0 1 6
   13{m
1 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 1 0 0

Finally I add the rows for each permutation, take the product to check if it's all 1, and
check if there is any 1 in each permuted array.
   * +/ 1= */"1 +/"2 m
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBJDsIwDLzziiigppsSG27pcuQF3BFFoIIqIbEcoiK@HtqmS5peYnvGnox91/qayR2RLIwEZqGgGAm69auaUyRF8OW/JgI9Eszj2t/EKlinN15lMhKRKDKZx9zjVHo8V0xfzuWDsMPz8y4VW3XVlaQ4ZTjmmJApb4v@mUDoALttRMDCwKAmtJVN9aCZsRmcc@CqNoLoCMPcMhjHA7GwhcO86Zvtwvan6qUYmQ4D7pb2nWDuzFlmgLofbQOJxTmHWXCdJqD@Aw)